# How to Handle the misfire in Quartz

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am working with Quartz

I have set

```
 CronTrigger trigger = newTrigger().
                withIdentity(triggerKey).
                withSchedule(
                cronSchedule(cronExpression).
                withMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing()  //or other
                ).build();
```

This is behaving when i restart the server. It's continuously printing info message that

```
"Handling the first 20 triggers that missed their scheduled fire-time. More misfired triggers remain to be processed
```

and not able to trigger the previously scheduled jobs. if i create a new schedule it triggers the only new job for old jobs it's keep on showing the above massage. 
Any one please help me to solve this

Answer (score -1):

While setting the trigger you have set to do nothing with the misFired triggers.So scheduler has just ignored the misfired triggers.

Comment: It looks to me like the questioner already has `withMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing()`. Could you suggest a code solution?